# Error openSSL appears to lack for elliptic curve cryptography? What's that mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: linux, compiling, openssl

I followed [this step](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch03.html#_btcd) to compile Bitcoin code, but got an error. Could you please explain what the problem is and how can it be resolved?

Error:

```
[root@localhost bitcoin-0.10.0rc1]# bitcoind
Error: OpenSSL appears to lack support for elliptic curve cryptography. For more information, visit https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OpenSSL_and_EC_Libraries
Error: Initialization sanity check failed. Bitcoin Core is shutting down.
[root@localhost bitcoin-0.10.0rc1]#
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to U&L SE, maybe this question better fit stackoverflow.

Comment: @Archemar not really, it is not a programming thing per se.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSSL on you system has been compiled without ECC support - likely you have an older system where it wasn't included, probably for patent reasons - see [ECC patents on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_patents).

To solve it, you need to update your OpenSSL package to one, that has ECC enabled.

Comment: For couple of days I am searching for OpenSSL Package with ECC enabled but I didn't find that. Will you please provide a step  to compile/build our own OpenSSL? Which Version I have to use who have OpenSSL with ECC enabled? Please let me know. thanks in advance

Comment: First of all you need to amend your question with the OS and version thereof you are using. Looking at the source package for your distribution should help (you might just need to rebuild it with some specific options set).

Comment: I am using fedora18, and what do you mean by source package for your distribution.